# How to check if array includes string in PUG template

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, express, pug

I am using NodeJS with Express and the PUG view engine.

I am attempting to check if an array contains a certain string. I have tried the builtin javascript methods such as:

```
array.includes(str)
array.indexOf(str) > -1.
```

However neither of these options seem to work. How can I check if an array contains a certain string in PUG?

```
if example_array.length > 0
  span() Array contains elements! // This works and appears on page
  if example_array.includes('example string') // This does not work
    span() Array includes example string! // This does not appear on page
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `example_array`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to run inline JS in your template you have to mark your code as unbuffered.
https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unbuffered-code

```
  if example_array.length > 0
     span() Array contains elements! 
     - if (example_array.includes('example string'))
       span() Array includes example string!
```

*Note the "-" in front of the "if" on line 3.*

Since this is a literal js expression now the parantheses are required aswell.

Comment: Do you mean parentheses instead of braces?

Answer (score 1):

This kept me busy for hours so I wanted to share my own solution. While the answer is correct when checking for a string directly, remember you may need to add `.toString()` if you're checking from a variable:

```
- if (example_array.includes(myVariable.toString()))
```

Hopefully this saves someone some time!